# Get Storefront Product URL for Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-urls, admin-url

I am trying to get the storefront product URL.

$_Product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product->getId());
echo $_Product->getUrlModel()->getUrl($_Product);

For some of the products, the URL is showing as the product admin url. i.e., http://example.com/admin/catalog/product/view/id/463/s/product-name/key/21e3132388ab54cb00eb98bd047bb535057a7e9e44efac8b79cfe599e7ec7bad/

I want the product URL as http://example.com/product-name.html

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code

```
$_Product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product->getId()); 
echo $_Product->getProductUrl();
```

Note : Don't use objectmanager directly in your .phtml instead use block or helper to load the product.

Comment: Tried that one as well. Still not working.

Comment: Try loading product using Repository, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to using this

```
    $productId = 1;

    $productRepository = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
    $product = $productRepository->getById($productId);
    $product->getProductUrl();
```

It just an example don't use objectManager directly you can inject the class Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface to constructor

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: try to print/log all product data like $product->getData() and check url is there

Answer (score 0):

```
$productRepository = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
$productBD = $productRepository->getById(your_product_id);
$productBD->getProductUrl()
```

in case you don't have your product ID you can get it by SKU using this:

```
$productRepository = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
$productID=$productRepository->getIdBySku($sku);
```

Make sure you are calling this in the context of a store view in wich your product exists !

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
namespace Name\Module\Helper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $productModel;
    protected $productRepository;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Product $productModel,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    )
    {
        $this->productModel = $productModel;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getProductUrl($productId, $storeId)
    {
        $product = $this->productModel->load($productId);
        $product->setStoreId($storeId);
        $url = $product->getProductUrl();
        // another way to get url
        $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId, false, $storeId);
        $productURL = $product->setStoreId($storeId)->getUrlModel()->getUrlInStore($product, ['_escape' => true]);
    }
}
```